# INDEX POR DEFECTO EN UNA SUBCARPETA EN GITHUB PAGES

Tags: git, github, github-pages

existe algún comando u opción en github page que me permita colocar un index por defecto una vez el usuario ingrese solo a la carpeta. Si se dan cuenta esta acción es lo mismo que la pagina principal de github pages, muestra el index.html que encuentre en la raíz pero no lo muestra en la URL. Quiero hacer lo mismo pero en las subcarpetas. ¿Será posible? O se puede acortar la URL en github, es decir si tengo lo siguiente pomitax.github.io/subcarpeta/subcarpeta/index.html ->  pomitax.github.io/index.html ¿También será posible? Un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No parece una pregunta relacionada con **git** (lo digo por la etiqueta).

Comment: lo puse porque la solucion pueda ser un comando de git que dezconozco